# How can I make KPI card's target goal dynamic in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I created the following vizualization in Power BI Desktop:
[image]

If I choose Calculation Level 2015 on the slicer, it is correct. The target goal should be 100.
However, when I choose MoM, the target goal should be 0.

How can I achieve this in Power BI? How can I make KPI's target goal responsive to slicer in Power BI?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new table called 'Calculation Types' (You could use 'Enter Data' if these values change very infrequently, or use a data source if one exists.) This table needs only contain the a list of 'Calculation Types' and your target value for each type.

Add a relationship between your source data and the 'Calculation Types' table on the 'Calculation Type' field.

Add the new 'target' field as the target for the KPI (Summarised by 'Max' or 'Min') then you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @JeffUK. I tried your approach. My problem is the following: when I tick 'Level 2015' I need the target summarised by 'Max' and when I tick "MoM" on the slicer, then I need the target 'Min'. How can I do that automatically?

Comment: @ÜbelYildmar you shouldn't need to, make sure you change the slicer to use the calculation type field from the new table too.